# convert array to json parse-sdk-php (Parse Server)

Tags: php, json, parse-server, slim-3

how to convert array results from ParseQuery() as JSON because the results always return as Array. In addition, am using Slim3 framework for routing.

```
$query = new ParseQuery("Friends");
$results = $query->find();
```

I searched a lot but without result.

var_dump results
https://pastebin.com/KDYcd5Cd

Any support please

Comment: You should try to use json_encode()

Comment: @RobertNegreanu return empty

Comment: Try to use "options" http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php Some example: http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/json/array.php

Comment: @RobertNegreanu return like this [{},{},{},{}]

Comment: @RobertNegreanu i think because there are private objects! what do you think?

Comment: can you share ``$results`` ``var_dump`` result ?

Comment: @MehmetSoylu Yup, added.

Comment: @AbdulazizM I think you're right and you have to serialize like here http://jondavidjohn.com/show-non-public-members-with-json_encode/

Comment: @RobertNegreanu Could you just give me one example on my results (var_dump)

Answer (score 0):

The objects in the array you are trying to `json_encode` have private properties, which are *not* accessible when dumping or encoding the object.

However, you can still achieve this by iterating over each object and calling `$obj->_encode()` individually. This will encode and return the properties that you're looking for.

Given that, something like this would suffice:

```php
$query = new ParseQuery("Friends");
$results = $query->find();

$encoded = [];

// iterate over and store each encoded result
foreach($results as $result) {
    $encoded[] = $result->_encode();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```php
$query = new ParseQuery("Friends");
$results = $query->find(false, false);
```

Comment: Could you add more explanation on why your code would work for the OP?